# Pandas DataFrame from stream of partial dictionaries

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a stream of packets coming in from multiple sources as python dictionaries with synchronized sequence numbers but different attributes.

```
{'seq': 1, 'A':0, 'B':2, 'C':3}
{'seq': 1, 'D':4, 'E':5, 'F':6}
{'seq': 2, 'A':7, 'B':8, 'C':9}
{'seq': 2, 'D':10, 'E':11, 'F':12}
{'seq': 3, 'D':400, 'E':500, 'F':600}
{'seq': 4, 'A':0.5, 'B':2.6, 'C':3.7}
{'seq': 3, 'A':100, 'B':200}
{'seq': 4, 'D':4.8, 'E':5.9, 'F':6.1}
...
```

I need to consolidate these into a Pandas DataFrame so that I can do further processing. Ideally something that looks like:

```
'seq'  'A'  'B'  'C'  'D'  'E'  'F'
   1    0    2    3    4    5    6
   2    7    8    9   10   11   12
   3  100  200  NaN  400  500  600
   4  0.5  2.6  3.7  4.8  5.9  6.1
 ...
```

Order of the incoming packets is not guaranteed, and the number and naming of attributes needs to be arbitrary (will add additional sources and/or attributes per source over time). Keys are consistent and values are generally numeric.

Over the past couple days of I've tried all sorts of calls to df.append, df.from_dict, pd.merge, pd.concat, df.align, etc. in various combinations with varying degrees of success. But I haven't been able to find the magic combination to pull all the partial successes together complete function.

```
Packet={'seq': 2, 'A':7, 'B':8, 'C':9}

def add_packet(pkt=Packet, df=pd.DataFrame())
    ??!#
    return updated_df
```

Any suggested solutions, examples or references are appreciated.

**Solution??**

I think I've got it by adding a call to `df.groupby('seq').first()` to the suggestion by RichieV.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'seq': 1, 'A':0, 'B':2, 'C':3},
...     {'seq': 1, 'D':4, 'E':5, 'F':6},
...     {'seq': 2, 'A':7, 'B':8, 'C':9},
...     {'seq': 2, 'D':10, 'E':11, 'F':12},
...     {'seq': 3, 'D':400, 'E':500, 'F':600},
...     {'seq': 4, 'A':0.5, 'B':2.6, 'C':3.7},
...     {'seq': 3, 'A':100, 'B':200},
...     {'seq': 4, 'D':4.8, 'E':5.9, 'F':6.1},
... ])
... 
... Packet={'seq': 2, 'A':7, 'B':8, 'C':9, 'H': 100}
... df = df.append(Packet, ignore_index=True)
... print(df)

   seq      A      B    C      D      E      F      H
0  1.0    0.0    2.0  3.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1  1.0    NaN    NaN  NaN    4.0    5.0    6.0    NaN
2  2.0    7.0    8.0  9.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3  2.0    NaN    NaN  NaN   10.0   11.0   12.0    NaN
4  3.0    NaN    NaN  NaN  400.0  500.0  600.0    NaN
5  4.0    0.5    2.6  3.7    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
6  3.0  100.0  200.0  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
7  4.0    NaN    NaN  NaN    4.8    5.9    6.1    NaN
8  2.0    7.0    8.0  9.0    NaN    NaN    NaN  100.0

grouped = df.groupby('seq').first()
print(grouped)
         A      B    C      D      E      F      H
seq                                               
1.0    0.0    2.0  3.0    4.0    5.0    6.0    NaN
2.0    7.0    8.0  9.0   10.0   11.0   12.0  100.0
3.0  100.0  200.0  NaN  400.0  500.0  600.0    NaN
4.0    0.5    2.6  3.7    4.8    5.9    6.1    NaN
```

Comment: {ValueError}If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: must it be stream? I ask because a faster approach would be to collect all the dictionaries, then reshape into a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

***Edit***

Adding `.groupby().first()` as you suggested would fix the data you have but in order to add a new packet after that you have to modify get the sequence and use as index to update your df.

```
def add_packet(pkt, df):
    seq = pkt.pop('seq')
    return df.combine_first(pd.DataFrame(pkt, index=[seq]))

packets = [
    {'seq': 1, 'A':0, 'B':2, 'C':3},
    {'seq': 1, 'D':4, 'E':5, 'F':6},
    {'seq': 2, 'A':7, 'B':8, 'C':9},
    {'seq': 2, 'D':10, 'E':11, 'F':12},
    {'seq': 3, 'D':400, 'E':500, 'F':600},
    {'seq': 4, 'A':0.5, 'B':2.6, 'C':3.7},
    {'seq': 3, 'A':100, 'B':200},
    {'seq': 4, 'D':4.8, 'E':5.9, 'F':6.1},
]
df = pd.DataFrame()
for pkt in packets:
    df = add_packet(pkt, df)
print(df)
```

Output

```
       A      B    C      D      E      F
1    0.0    2.0  3.0    4.0    5.0    6.0
2    7.0    8.0  9.0   10.0   11.0   12.0
3  100.0  200.0  NaN  400.0  500.0  600.0
4    0.5    2.6  3.7    4.8    5.9    6.1
```

---

***First attempt***

It works fine for me, `append` can take your dictionary and even assign new columns

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'seq': 1, 'A':0, 'B':2, 'C':3},
    {'seq': 1, 'D':4, 'E':5, 'F':6},
    {'seq': 2, 'A':7, 'B':8, 'C':9},
    {'seq': 2, 'D':10, 'E':11, 'F':12},
    {'seq': 3, 'D':400, 'E':500, 'F':600},
    {'seq': 4, 'A':0.5, 'B':2.6, 'C':3.7},
    {'seq': 3, 'A':100, 'B':200},
    {'seq': 4, 'D':4.8, 'E':5.9, 'F':6.1},
])

Packet={'seq': 2, 'A':7, 'B':8, 'C':9, 'H': 100}
df = df.append(Packet, ignore_index=True)
print(df)

   seq      A      B    C      D      E      F      H
0  1.0    0.0    2.0  3.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1  1.0    NaN    NaN  NaN    4.0    5.0    6.0    NaN
2  2.0    7.0    8.0  9.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
3  2.0    NaN    NaN  NaN   10.0   11.0   12.0    NaN
4  3.0    NaN    NaN  NaN  400.0  500.0  600.0    NaN
5  4.0    0.5    2.6  3.7    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
6  3.0  100.0  200.0  NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
7  4.0    NaN    NaN  NaN    4.8    5.9    6.1    NaN
8  2.0    7.0    8.0  9.0    NaN    NaN    NaN  100.0
```

Keep in mind that appending one row at a time is a lot less efficient than collecting new packets in a list and appending/concatenating as a batch.

Comment: A key requirement is that attributes for a given sequence number be consolidated into a single row of the data frame.